# "OSError: Model name './XX' was not found in tokenizers model name list" - cannot load custom tokenizer in Transformers

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, sentencepiece

I'm trying to create my own tokenizer with my own dataset/vocabulary using Sentencepiece and then use it with AlbertTokenizer transformers.

I followed really closely the tutorial on how to train a model from scratch by HuggingFace: https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/blog/blob/master/notebooks/01_how_to_train.ipynb#scrollTo=hO5M3vrAhcuj

```
    # import relevant libraries   
    from pathlib import Path
    from tokenizers import SentencePieceBPETokenizer
    from tokenizers.implementations import SentencePieceBPETokenizer
    from tokenizers.processors import BertProcessing
    from transformers import AlbertTokenizer
    

    paths = [str(x) for x in Path("./data").glob("**/*.txt")]
    

    # Initialize a tokenizer
    tokenizer = SentencePieceBPETokenizer(add_prefix_space=True)
    
    # Customize training
    tokenizer.train(files=paths, 
                    vocab_size=32000, 
                    min_frequency=2, 
                    show_progress=True,
                    special_tokens=['<unk>'],)

    # Saving model
    tokenizer.save_model("Sent-AlBERT")


    tokenizer = SentencePieceBPETokenizer(
        "./Sent-AlBERT/vocab.json",
        "./Sent-AlBERT/merges.txt",)

    tokenizer.enable_truncation(max_length=512)
```

Everything is fine up until this point when I tried to re-create the tokenizer in transformers

```
    # Re-create our tokenizer in transformers
        tokenizer = AlbertTokenizer.from_pretrained("./Sent-AlBERT", do_lower_case=True)
```

This is the error message I kept receiving:

```
OSError: Model name './Sent-AlBERT' was not found in tokenizers model name list (albert-base-v1, albert-large-v1, albert-xlarge-v1, albert-xxlarge-v1, albert-base-v2, albert-large-v2, albert-xlarge-v2, albert-xxlarge-v2). We assumed './Sent-AlBERT' was a path, a model identifier, or url to a directory containing vocabulary files named ['spiece.model'] but couldn't find such vocabulary files at this path or url.
```

For some reason, it works with RobertaTokenizerFast but not with AlbertTokenzier.

If anyone could give me a suggestion or any sort of direction on how to use Sentencepiece with AlberTokenizer I would really appreciate.

Comment: I haven't looked to deep into it, but the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/albert.html#alberttokenizer) mentions that the tokenizer uses a file with `spm` extension and not the vocab.json. The sourcecode of the [AlbertTokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/models/albert/tokenization_albert.html#AlbertTokenizer) is also importing the sentencepiece library. The provided Albert models don't have a vocab.json. Furthermore, huggingface does also not provide an AlbertFastTokenizer. 1/2

Comment: My guess is therefore, that the you can not initialize the AlbertTokenizer with files from the `tokenizers` library. You either need to train one with the [sentencepiece](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece) library or you use one tokenizer from huggingface that uses a sentencepieceBPE approach. Maybe it is even possible to convert the `vocab.txt` and `merges.txt` to an `.spm`. 2/2